# datepicker jquery ui change date format to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

For picking the dates in a form I am using the JQuery UI datepicker. I know the option for setting another `dateFormat` like so `$( ".selector" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});`. Is it possible to change this to text, so if I pick the second of March (this will get me 02-03-2017 with the option above) it will give me 2 March 2017? I have looked into the `dateFormat` option but I can't get it right.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of formatting options is [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate). For your desired format, it should be:

```
$(".selector").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "d MM yy"
});
```

- `d` - day of month (no leading zero)
- `MM` - month name long
- `yy` - year (four digit)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "d MM yy");
```

or

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ "dateFormat": "d MM yy" });
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a5r3d3st/)**